# Using Win32 API functionality along with/from pthreads

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, pthreads

I have my own threading library built using TinyThread++. It works quite well, and it was also a great learning experience for me. I have my own datastructures for passing around messages, and the interface makes good sense to me, primarily because I was its author.

Whenever a thread is created in my system, it runs in a loop, and checks for messages occasionally via a message passing protocol of my own devising.

Now I want to start using some Windows API functionality, and windows has its own set of conventions and message queues, etc. Now I'm pretty sure that TinyThread++ uses pthreads. Since I'm using MinGW, I'm wondering if pthreads is being implemented on windows threads. If this is the case, I may be able to just treat my pthreads-threads as windows-threads. But if not, I suspect I might run into some strange behavior.

**edit:** looking at the `thread` type given by Tinythread++ it looks like it actually uses the windows `HANDLE` to keep track of the threads and even uses `_beginthreadex` to spawn them.

My question is, will Windows be happy if I go around calling `SetWindowsHookEx` from some point in my pthreads code? I realize I need to have a Windows message polling loop in the same thread. I intend to do something like this:

```
try {

    HHOOK mousehook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc,
        NULL, 0);
    if (mousehook == NULL) printf("Mousehook error %u\n",GetLastError());

    while(true) {
        MSG msg;
        if (GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(mousehook);

    printf("Procedure completed without exceptional events.\n");

} catch (...) {
    printf("Exception!\n");
}
```

Comment: You're never going to exit that `while` loop.

Comment: You are correct. I have yet to figure out how I may handle cleanup.

Comment: @GSerg, since `GetMessage` returns 0 when receiving `WM_QUIT` I should just break out of the while loop at that point, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. `If(!GetMessage()) break; TranslateMessage(); DispatchMessage();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine.

You may run into trouble if you try to pass pthread thread ids to Windows threading functions which want a thread HANDLE, but here you just need the loop to stay in the same thread as `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Answer (score 0):

Pthreads don't exist on windows, unless you're using something like cygwin. Either way, the API docs say SetWindowsHookEx associates hooks for application events tied to a particular thread, OR to the desktop on which your app is running. So it can handle being called in a thread, but you need to read the docs so that you call it in a way that gives you the ehavior you want.